# Progressive Dinner: 9 couples and 15 couples scenario

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm organising a progressive dinner with 9 couples, where each couple has to host one course, either a starter, a main course or a dessert and each hosting has two pairs of guests. After each course the hosts and guests all separate and go to the next venue. They never meet the same couples twice. I think I can do this with 9 couples and then 15 couples. Can anyone help with charts for both scenarios please?

Comment: Do the individuals in each couple split up each time? If so, are couples gendered?

Comment: No each couple stays together but after having their course they move separately to another venue than the host where they've just been hosted and the other couple who were guests.

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework problem pretending to be a real one. So the question is pertinent: what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Not homework. Real problem. Just thought there'd be a mathematical solution that someone would know.